# Can't find resourceClick like eventClick in fullcalendar scheduler @5.7.0

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I've faced to problem. Fullcalendar has property eventClick which allows you to handle a click on an event from list events calendar. Now I've started use fullcalendar scheduler (@5.7.0) where I need to click and call such action but on resource, from list resources in the left side. I've couldn't find any solutions so decided to write feature request. If solvetion has already existed, couldn't you share information and write to way to use resourceClick in fullcalendar scheduler @5.7.0.

I think it featuer will be usefule for many projects, where use resource timeline.

Comment: If you want to make a feature request, you need to follow the instructions at https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features . We cannot deal with feature requests here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: P.S. You are correct - there is no "resourceClick" functionality currently.